# Get multiple fields from entity in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, key-value-observing

I am trying to fetch multiple fields from a core data entity.  Following code will work to fetch one field. What is syntax for two fields?

```
NSMutableArray *areas = [[addresses valueForKey:@"area"] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you are searching for

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:(NSArray *)keys
```

Comment: how would you specify keys?  Can you specify more than one?

Comment: the argument is an array
`NSDictionary *values = [addresses dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:@[@"area", @"zip"]];`
gives you a dictionary of values where property names are dictionary keys

Comment: Is there some sort of indexing system to this so that if you get back 3 results, i.e. new york, chicago, los angeles, 10036, 11362, 90004 you can relate the area to the zip?

Comment: OK.  I got both attributes.  Still need to figure out how to relate one to another id by index or something.

Comment: Perhaps you need to provide us with a better (more complete) example. Then we can dig deeper.